# Soundcloud - Ruby creating a Playlist getting 422 (#soundcloud-ruby)

Tags: ruby, soundcloud

I suspect something at Soundcloud has changed because my code has not been altered and worked fine last year.

I see:

```
Error: HTTP status: 422 Unprocessable Entity, Status Code: 422, playlist_struct:{:title=>"Y11 - REVO - Sop", :description=>"Y11 - REVO - Sop newchoir", :tag_list=>"Sop", :tracks=>"219269586", :format=>"json", :oauth_token=>"..."}
```

My oauth_token works fine.

I call:

```
  new_playlist = @client.post('/playlists', playlist_struct)
```

Where @client is defined using https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-ruby as:

```
@client = SoundCloud.new({
                             :client_id     => clientId,
                             :client_secret => clientSecret,
                             :username      => email,
                             :password      => password
                         })
```

And playlist_struct is per the error message.

Thoughts appreciated!

Regards, M.

Full code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'soundcloud'
require 'pp'
require 'logger'

def login
  # http://soundcloud.com/you/apps
  clientId = '...'
  clientSecret = '...'
  email = '...'
  password = '...'


  # register a new client, which will exchange the username, password for an access_token
  # NOTE: the SoundCloud API Docs advise not to use the user credentials flow in a web app.
  # In any case, never store the password of a user.
  @client = SoundCloud.new({
                             :client_id     => clientId,
                             :client_secret => clientSecret,
                             :username      => email,
                             :password      => password
                           })

  # print logged in username
  puts"h1. Logged in as " + @client.get('/me').username 

  # updating the users profile description
end

login()


playlist_struct = {
  :title => "Hello"
}


  new_playlist = @client.post('/playlists', playlist_struct)
  @log.info ' OK: '+new_playlist.permalink_url
```

Comment: Did you try to update your ruby gem?

Comment: Well, good point, I hadn't. I just updated to soundcloud-0.3.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed soundcloud-0.3.2. STILL FAILS. :(

Comment: Merely updating the gem doesn't change the version used by the application. You should `bundle update` so that the changes take effect in `Gemfile.lock`. Also, please make sure that you are not enforcing any version of the soundcloud gem in `Gemfile`.

Comment: Thanks, but according to: /Volumes/Storage/martincleaver/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/soundcloud-0.3.2/lib/soundcloud/client.rb:152:in `handle_response': HTTP status: 422 Unprocessable Entity (SoundCloud::ResponseError)
 from /Volumes/Storage/martincleaver/.chefdk/gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/soundcloud-0.3.2/lib/soundcloud/client.rb:32:in `post'
 from playlist_builder.rb:422:in `make_playlist'
I am using the latest.

Comment: could you show us the code that fails ? have you tried simplifying the playlist_struct by starting with one criterium and building up untik you get the error ?  can you make the same request witha a browser ?

Comment: See above. I've added a minimal extract that shows the problem.

Comment: Do I need to provide anything else?

Comment: I've answered Peter's 1&2. For clarity, yes, 3, I can make the same request within the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the playlist_struct now needs to include

playlist: { 
   ...
}

Around the content.

As the code worked for a couple of years before hand I'd venture this is a silent change to the API.